# Prove that if $1 \leq p \leq q \leq \infty$, then $||x||_q \leq ||x||_p$, for every $x \in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

(Hint) Consider the case $||x||_{p} = 1$.

So far I have that $1= |x_{1}|^p+|x_2|^{p}+..+|x_{n}|^{p}$, because I used the fact that $||x||_{p}=1$. Why do I have to use the positive homogeneity property for norms? 
So now all of the $x_{i}$ elements are all less than $1$ for it to equal $1$. So that means $P$ has to be greater than $1$ for this to make sense right? Then, from here, I don't know where to go...

Comment: It is helpful to point out which part of the proof you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to apply the hint: if $\|x\|_p = 1$ then each component $x_i$ is less than or equal to $1$. In particular $|x_i|^p \ge |x_i|^q$ for each $i$. This means $$ 1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p \ge \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^q = \|x\|_q^q.$$ Take the $q$ root on each side to get $\|x\|_q \le 1 = \|x\|_p$.

In general use $\|ax\|_p = a\|x\|_p$ whenever $a > 0$, and choose $a$ carefully.

Comment: Why do I have to use the positive homogeneity property? Thank you

Comment: You don't have to do anything. It is convenient if you want to apply the hint. What if $a = \|x\|_p^{-1}$?

Comment: Hey so this is what I have so far , and entering in your text.

Comment: I WTS that $||x||_{q} \leq ||x||_{p}$. By positive homogenity, $|x|_{q} \leq |x|_{p} iff. | \lamdax|_{q}= \leq  \lamda|x|_{p} = |\lamdax|_{p}$ For some $\lamda >0$. So WLOG, $||x||_{p}=1$. and then i go on with your example and it shows that $||x||_{p} \geq ||x||_{q}$

Comment: If $a = \|x\|_p^{-1}$ then $\|ax\|_p = 1$ so that $$a\|x\|_q = \|ax\|_q \le \|ax\|_p = 1.$$ Now multiply by $a$.

Answer (score 0):

$L_{P}$s are comparable when they are in finite spaces.

Comment: So how would we show for $q \leq \infty$ ?

Answer (score 0):

More generally given that $ 1 \leq p < q < \infty $ you can prove that $||a||_q \leq ||a||_p$ for a sequence of real numbers $a = (a_n)$ verifying $a \in l_p $.

1- Indeed $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that because of the sum of positive numbers:
$$||a||_p^{q-p}=(|a_1|^p+|a_2|^p+...+|a_n|^p+...)^{\frac{q-p}{p}} \geq |a_n|^{\frac{q-p}{p}}=|a_n|^{q-p} \Rightarrow \forall n , |a_n|^q \leq ||a||^{q-p}_p |a_n|^p$$

2- According to "1-" we can write.
$$||a||_q = (|a_1|^q+|a_2|^q+...+|a_n|^q+...)^{\frac{1}{q}} \leq (||a||^{q-p}_p |a_1|^p+ ||a||^{q-p}_p |a_2|^p + ... + ||a||^{q-p}_p |a_n|^p +...)^{\frac{1}{q}} = ||a||_p^{\frac{q-p}{q}}||a||_p^{\frac{p}{q}} = ||a||_p^{\frac{q-p}{q} + \frac{p}{q}}  = ||a||_p$$

And this finish the prove.